# Prove family of disjoint finite-measure subsets is countable

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A\in\mathcal F$ of $\sigma$-finite $\mu$ measure. Let $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F$ be a family of disjoints subsets of $A$. Prove that the subfamily of $\mathcal G$ for which $\mu(B)<\infty$,$B\in \mathcal G$ is countable.

So I defined $\mathcal D=\{B\in\mathcal G:\mu(B)>0\}$. I have to show that $\mathcal D$ is countable.

Since $A\in\mathcal F$ of $\sigma$-finite $\mu$ measure, then $A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, where $\mu(A_i)<\infty$.

We can write $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$ where $C_n$ are disjoints, $\mu(C_n)<\infty$. So $C_n\in \mathcal D$.

I am not sure how to continue. Is this right so far?

Comment: Your revised definition of $\mathcal D$ didn't make much sense; I fixed it for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, thank you.

Comment: If $A$ has finite $\mu$ measure, we can use contradiction. If $D$ is uncountable, then $\{B \in G : \mu(B) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ is uncountable for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies $\mu(A) \geq \infty$. Maybe there is a way to salvage this argument for when $A$ is sigma-finite.